# Xcode4.0.2 Run debug on device iphone4

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator

I don't know why, I install Xcode 4.0.2 and I run debug on device Iphone4 version 4.3.

It's work. But when I installed Iphone IOS5.0 I can't run device.

How to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to download Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5 SDK from the developer site to build and debug on iOS 5 devices